# Robot test receiving different unicode than was sent from python keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework, python-unicode

I have robot test that calls a python function to list files in a given path recursively. That function returns a list of all the full pathes like this:

```
@keyword('List Files Recursively')
def list_files_rec_filtered(path, regexp_filter="^(?!\.).+$"):
    file_list = []
    filename_filter = re.compile(regexp_filter)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
        for file in files:
            if filename_filter.match(file):
                file_list.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root,file)))
    return file_list
```

When calling this function from a robot keyword, I can see that I get a different result than what was in the list in python.

```
${files} = file_utils.List Files Recursively  ${path}  ${FILE_TYPES}
```

I have a file that has ジ (U+30B7, U+3099) in the name before it's returned, but the returned value is instead ジ (U+30B8). I took both characters from the robot test's logfile, first one is a debug message I generated with python's `print()`, the second one is from robots own `TRACE Return:` value.

Comment: Are there approaches you've already tried and didn't work for you?

Comment: In the beginning I thought it was the way I created they file_list that did some implicit casting, but apparently it is not. So either the return itself is doing some implicit casting or the robot framework itself. Or it might be an operating system issue.

Comment: Which encoding is the native Python variable content?

Comment: I don't know, how would I check that?

Comment: path is a str, so is the elements in the list. so it's unicode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned it's due to the APFS. Robot normalizes Unicode strings to NFC, but Python uses the NFD it gets from the APFS. There is not really a solution, only workarounds. Apple needs to fix how the APFS bug handles NFC/NFD collisions as shown here: https://eclecticlight.co/2017/04/06/apfs-is-currently-unusable-with-most-non-english-languages/ - almost every app on OSX is affected by this, including the Finder and the Preview.